# Group rows starting with same number into single row MS Access SQl

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sum

I have an MS access table containing the following values

```
ID    Value
1.1    5
1.2    5
1.3    2
2.1    3
2.2    1
2.3    9
```

Is there a way to get the sum of the values start start with the same ID (e.g. summ all values that start with 1 or 2)

Comment: Can you specify the expected result as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the part to the left of the decimal:

```
select left(id, instr(id, '.') - 1), sum(value)
from t
group by left(id, instr(id, '.') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id`s are numbers (as they look like), you can use `int()` to extract their integer part, and aggregate by that:

```
select int(id) id, sum(value) sum_value from mytabel group by int(id)
```